# Get Knowledge Article Record Type using REST API

Tags: api, salesforce

Is it possible to get the record type of articles using REST API? I can get a list of articles using this

> /services/data/v38.0/support/knowledgeArticles?sort=ViewScore&channel=App&pageSize=3

but there's no record type available. Please help me. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge articles are spread across multiple objects.  Try querying (or probably better to search with SOSL) the KnowledgeArticleVersion (Id, Title, Summary, ArticleType, KnowledgeArticleId) object and then depending on the article type you can search that specific knowledge article version object (__kav) for example Test__kav to get the specific article.

In summary try:

```
/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/KnowledgeArticleVersion
```

and then the article types specific to your org

Edit
This might be easier:

```
/services/data/v37.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+ArticleType,+KnowledgeArticleId+FROM+KnowledgeArticleVersion+WHERE+PublishStatus='online'
```

You might need to add language code if u have multiple languages enabled, but this would tell you the Article type for the articles in question

Comment: thank you for the reply. But how do you implement this article type specific? I tried the api call and get result. I tried this /services/data/v38.0/sobjects/KnowledgeArticleVersion/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields as one of the result as url but somehow give me erros. Can you give me more details? I having problem understanding this. thank you

Comment: thank you for this but it shows 400 (Bad Request) error

Comment: You sometimes need language also it depends on what features you have enabled for you knowledge setup. The error details should tell you what was missing.